# Kafka auth failed while implementing GSSAPI auth in Nodejs app

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, gssapi, kafkajs

I’m currently looking to connect my nodejs app (using kafkajs package) with
a kerberised kafka cluster (GSSAPI enabled, openldap) but facing the
SASL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error when trying to authenticate with a SPNEGO
token.

Kafkajs library has no built in support for GSSAPI mechanism. I’m not sure
if it’s the right approach but I have come as far as getting a ticket from
the openldap server and creating a SPNEGO token (base64) from it but don’t
know what approach to take further.

I think encoding is the issue here but I’m a newbie at it and seeking out
guidance on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If using node-rdkafka is an option. It does support SASL as it wrapps librdkafka.

You can find the documentation on [using SASL with librdkafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka)